# Where to put the Method? Class/Module Responsibility

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to determine which Module(s) should be responsible for my custom output methods.

I have the following setup:

```
|-main.py
|-libs
    |-Car (attr: Tires, Seats, Doors, Engine)
        |-Tires  (attr: size, age, brand)
        |-Seats (attr: number, material)
        |-Doors (attr: number)
        |-Engine (attr: size, make, model, torque)
```

now my main.py converts all types of data sources into standard Car Objects. But then it will output pieces of information about the cars. Each submodule (Tires-Engine) is a class attribute of the Car class.

Where do you think it best to put the print/output responsibilities? Do they sit in main, because it handles output to different places? Does it sit in Car, since that's my main object or do I put print() methods in each submodule, since they know about their own attributes? (what I'm leaning towards).   Right now the submodules inherit from (object), not Car, just FYI.

I appreciate the advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest doing it in Car.

Your car.py is kind of a model class, that's well defined and your `main.py` is like a mesh of serializers, so I want to take inspiration from `Django`. In Django, it's recommended to overwrite `__unicode__()` to give a serializer-independent stdout representation of the model.